# node.js svn update/commit synchronously?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, svn

I'm using [svn-spawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svn-spawn) library to update/commit files to svn. Problem is my app calls svn up/commit in a loop, and because of the async nature of the call, svn-up is called from the next iteration of the loop before the previous svn-up can finish.
How to handle this issue? Is there any way to prevent the next call from happening until the previous one is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do it using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module.
[async.series](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) can be used to execute async tasks in a serial fashion.
This is how I did it.

```
function commitFile(arg, callback) {
    svnClient.getStatus(filePath, function(err, data) {
        //...
        svnClient.commit(['Commit msg', filePath], callback);
        //...
    });
}
var toCommit = [];
for (var i = 0, len = requests.length; i < len; i++) {
    //Adding files to commit, async.apply enables adding arguments to the anonymous function
    toCommit.push(async.apply(function(arg, cb) {
        commitFile(arg, cb);
    }, 'arg1'));
}
async.series(toCommit,function (err, result) {
    console.log('Final callback');
    if(err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    } else {
        console.log('result of this run: ' + result);
    }
});
```

async.series needs an array of functions which must call a callback once they are done. It uses the callback to determine that the current function in done executing and only then it will pick the next function to execute.